# Replacing character in href zip_ to zip

Tags: javascript, jquery

This jQuery code works half the time depending on browser. Is there a better way to write this replace. Change and href link with `.zip_` to `.zip`

```
jQuery("a[href*='.zip_']").each(function() {
  jQuery(this).attr("href", jQuery(this).attr("href").replace(/\.zip_/g, ".zip"));
});
```

Comment: This looks fine, it should work everywhere.

Comment: Make sure you run it inside `$(document).ready()`.

Comment: There's nothing inherently wrong with the code. Can you show an example case of it not working. Also note that the code could be reduced to just: `$("a[href*='.zip_']").attr('href', (i, h) => h.replace(/\.zip_/g, ".zip")));`

Comment: @Barmar thanks that did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is fine but it could be broken up a little bit to make it easier to read. I would personally use:

```
jQuery("a[href*='.zip_']").each(function() {
  const attr = jQuery(this).attr("href").split(".");
  attr[attr.length - 1] = ".zip";
  jQuery(this).attr("href", attr.join(''));
});
```

This should work as [Mozilla suggests](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) split works in all browsers.
Also make sure you are using this in your `$(document).ready()`.
This also makes the assumption .zip is  at the end of the href.

Comment: I am receiving `filename.zip_.zip` instead of `filename.zip`

Comment: @acctman Can you specify what the hrefs look like before you parse them? Is .zip at the end?